# Is temperature of crystallisation same as melting point temperature for polymers?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, polymers

Melting point tends to be a temperature range. Is it true that the temperature of crystallisation is the highest temperature at which the polymer melts and thus there is some distinction between temperature of crystallisation, T<sub>c</sub> and temperature at melting point, T<sub>m</sub>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is temperature of crystallization same as melting point temperature for polymers?

In a word: **NO.**

If you undrestand what the glass transition, crystallization and melting temperatures are it will make sense why they are not the same. [This paper](https://polymerscience.physik.hu-berlin.de/docs/manuals/DSC.pdf) does an excellent job at explaining the three concepts but I will summarize.

The **glass transition temperature** is the temperature where polymer chains become sufficiently mobile that the material transforms from being brittle to being soft and plastic (neither exo- nor endothermic, but does the heat capacity does increase). The **crystallization temperature** is the temperature where the molecules are mobile enough to rearrange into ordered arrangements (crystallize not decrystallize; this is an exothermic process; see plot below). The **melting temperature**  is where the polymer chains can freely move and ordered arrangements are disrupted (this annihilates any prior crystallization; an endothermic process).

[image]
<sub>Source: [Plastic Technology Laboratories](http://www.ptli.com/testlopedia/tests/dsc-d3417.asp)</sub>